# Как ограничить область показа google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Нужно сделать так, чтобы определённая область(от такой-то до такой-то широты, от такой-то до такой-то долготы) на гугл-картах под андроид показывалась, а остальную карту мира посмотреть было нельзя.

Есть ли такая функциональность из коробки или это нужно делать как-то через OnCameraChangeListener например?

Если кто-то с таким сталкивался, как это проще всего реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ это отслеживать через Listener изменение положения камеры, и если кординаты вылезают за пределы доступных, то присвоить им ближайшие дозволенные, т.е. переместить туда камеру, таким образом пользователь сможет немного вылезти за границу выбранной области, но сразу же будет перенесен обратно в область.